# Count Function - Codeigniter and MySQL

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table as below:

table name: brand

```
id  |   brand
1   |   UNIQLO
2   |   PDI
3   |   PDI
4   |   H&M
5   |   UNIQLO
```

The result that I need is:

```
PDI    x 2
UNIQLO x 2
H&M    x 1
```

I have tried this :

```
 $this->db->select('brand, count(*) as TOTAL');
   $this->db->from('brand'); 
   $this->db->group_by('id');
   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result();
```

But  my output is `uniqlopdiuniqlopdiH&Muniqlo`.

Anyone can solve my problem?

Comment: You need to apply the group aggregate on `brand` not `id`.  So `->group_by('brand')`

Comment: i tried before.the result is uniqlopdiH&M

Comment: You have only posted your querying code, not your display code.  The select statement `SELECT brand, COUNT(*) as TOTAL FROM brand GROUP BY brand` would produce the desired count aggregates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Berkowski is right
It should be group by brand.

Your query will be like this

```
$this->db->select('brand, count(*) as TOTAL');
$this->db->from('brand'); 
$this->db->group_by('brand');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```